# Make an n x n-1 matrix from 1 x n vector where the i-th row is the vector without the i-th element, without a for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I need this for Lagrange polynomials. I'm curious how one would do this without a `for` loop. The code currently looks like this:

```
tj = 1:n;
ti = zeros(n,n-1);
for i = 1:n
    ti(i,:) = tj([1:i-1, i+1:end]);
end
```

My `tj` is not really just a `1:n` vector but that's not important. While this `for` loop gets the job done, I'd rather use some matrix operation. I tried looking for some appropriate matrices to multiply it with, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
v = [10 20 30 40]; %// example vector
n = numel(v);
M = repmat(v(:), 1, n);
M = M(~eye(n));
M = reshape(M,n-1,n).';
```

gives

```
M =
    20    30    40
    10    30    40
    10    20    40
    10    20    30
```

Answer (score 1):

This should generalize to any `n`

```
ti = flipud(reshape(repmat(1:n, [n-1 1]), [n n-1]));
```

Taking a closer look at what's going on. If you look at the resulting matrix closely, you'll see that it's `n-1` 1's, `n-1` 2's, etc. from the bottom up.

**For the case where `n` is 3.**

```
ti =

     2     3
     1     3
     1     2
```

So we can flip this vertically and get

```
f = flipud(ti);

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3
```

Really this is `[1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3]` reshaped to be 3 x 2 rather than 2 x 3.

In that line of thinking

```
a = repmat(1:3, [2 1])

     1     2     3
     1     2     3

b = reshape(a, [3 2]);

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3

c = flipud(b);

     2     3
     1     3
     1     2
```

We are now back to where you started when we bring it all together and replace 3's with `n` and 2's with `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. First create a matrix where each row is the vector `tj` but are stacked on top of each other. Next, extract the lower and upper triangular parts of the matrix **without** the diagonal, then add the results together ensuring that you remove the last column of the lower triangular matrix and the first column of the upper triangular matrix.

```
n = numel(tj);
V = repmat(tj, n, 1);
L = tril(V,-1);
U = triu(V,1);
ti = L(:,1:end-1) + U(:,2:end);
```

[`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) finds the total number of values in `tj` which we store in `n`.  [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) facilitates the stacking of the vector `tj` to create a matrix that is `n x n` large.  After, we use [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) and [`triu`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) so that we extract the lower and upper triangular parts of the matrices **without** the diagonal.  In addition, the rest of the matrix is all zero except for the relevant triangular parts.  The `-1` and `1` flags for `tril` and `triu` respectively extract this out successfully while ensuring that the diagonal is all zero.  This creates a column of extra zeroes appearing at the last column when calling `tril` and the first column when calling `triu`.  The last part is to simply add these two matrices together ignoring the last column of the `tril` result and the first column of the `triu` result.

Given that `tj = [10 20 30 40];` (borrowed from Luis Mendo's example), we get:

```
ti =

    20    30    40
    10    30    40
    10    20    40
    10    20    30
```